# how to solve this error when trying to run rake server or rackup config.ru

Tags: ruby

wairi@my-pc:~/Development/code/phase-3/phase-3-sinatra-with-active-record-post-patch-delete$ bundle exec rake server
[DEPRECATED] `Bundler.with_clean_env` has been deprecated in favor of `Bundler.with_unbundled_env`. If you instead want the environment before bundler was originally loaded, use `Bundler.with_original_env` (called at /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/rerun-0.14.0/lib/rerun/notification.rb:74)

16:09:18 [rerun] Phase-3-sinatra-with-active-record-post-patch-delete launched
16:09:18 [rerun] Rerun (31476) running Phase-3-sinatra-with-active-record-post-patch-delete (31493)
/var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/handler.rb:45:in `pick': Couldn't find handler for: puma, thin, falcon, webrick. (LoadError) from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/handler.rb:60:in` default'
from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:334:in `server' from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:255:in` block in logging_middleware'
from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:413:in `block in build_app' from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:412:in` reverse_each'
from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:412:in `build_app' from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in` wrapped_app'
from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start' from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in` handle_profiling'
from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start' from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/lib/rack/server.rb:168:in` start'
from /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.7/bin/rackup:5:in `<top (required)>' from /usr/local/bin/rackup:25:in` load'
from /usr/local/bin/rackup:25:in `'

16:09:20 [rerun] Phase-3-sinatra-with-active-record-post-patch-delete Launch Failed
16:09:20 [rerun] Watching . for **/*.{rb,js,coffee,css,scss,sass,erb,html,haml,ru,yml,slim,md,feature,c,h} with Linux adapter
^[[A^C
16:14:14 [rerun] Phase-3-sinatra-with-active-record-post-patch-delete stopping

*actually i realised the lab had an issue on chosing which gem to use.I added `gem 'thin'`  inside gemfile and it worked you can also try `gem 'puma'*

Answer (score 0):

it appears that Rack is unable to find a suitable server handler to run your application.
Verify Gemfile: Ensure that you have added the appropriate server handler gem (e.g., gem 'thin' or gem 'puma') to your Gemfile and saved the changes.

Run bundle install: Execute the command bundle install in your project directory to make sure all the gems, including the server handler gem, are installed.

Restart the terminal or shell: If you recently installed the server handler gem, it's a good idea to restart your terminal or shell session to ensure the changes take effect.